# How come I can't import nltk even it's already installed successfully?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nltk

Hi I tried to install nltk from the vscode terminal which is said to be successful but I am still not able to import nltk on python. It said 'no module named'nltk''.

I attached my screenshot for clearer picture of my work. Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that the console enters the environment you are using.

   Since the environment you choose in Jupyter is `"myenv":conda`, select this environment in the lower left corner of VSCode, and use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal, VSCode will automatically enter the environment you selected. (You can refer to my screenshot: Result)
2. Install the module "`nltk`" in the current environment. `pip install nltk` or `pip3 install nltk`
3. Result:

   [image]

check:

1. Check the source of the installation tool `pip`, the installed package is placed in this environment.

   [image]
2. Check the installation package: "`pip list`"

   [image]

If you encounter any problems, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, Jill!! Very helpful! I can download nltk and run successfully now!